# change hosting password running drupal 7. any suggestions

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, passwords

I've a website running with `Drupal 7` on a Linux distro. Now I want to change password of the hosting account. is it normal? and what I need to know more about that?

is this will affect the `drupal` installation? if so then please let me know[or guide/redirect] some concrete solution to that..

I'll be very thankful
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you mean your ssh (or cpanel/etc.?) password by "hosting account". This should not have an impact : only the database password would have an impact on Drupal.

Comment: Yeah, cPanel, I think that is fine, but in terms, if I change hosting password, then from where I can change password for DB?

Comment: There should be a place for this in cpanel, but I don't have a site under cpanel at this time, so I'm afraid I can't help with this. You might already know this, but just in case : if the db password changes, you need to go in sites/[your site]/settings.php to change it in Drupal.